# SkAction not running on SKShapenode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Creating a circle using SKShapeNode then creating an action to rotate the circle but nothing is happening. When I change the action to apply to a SKSpriteNode it works.

Adding the Circle:

```
//adding largeCircle
let largeCircleRadius : CGFloat = 199
var largeCirclePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
let startAngle : CGFloat = 6.64
let endAngle : CGFloat = 2 * 6.64
CGPathAddArc(largeCirclePath, nil, 0.0, 0.0, largeCircleRadius, startAngle, endAngle , true)
let round = SKShapeNode(path: largeCirclePath, centered: false)

round.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.45, green: 0.45, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1)
round.lineWidth = 5
round.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame) / 2.0, CGRectGetHeight(frame) / 2.0)
round.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: largeCirclePath)
round.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = roundGroup
round.zPosition = 2
self.addChild(round)
```

Action:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    func movePlatform() {
        let oneRevolution = SKAction.rotateByAngle(360, duration: 1.0)
        let repeat = SKAction.repeatAction(oneRevolution, count: 1)
        round.runAction(repeat)      
    }
    movePlatform();
}
```

Comment: but … what if you choose `true` for `let round = …, centered: true)` ?

Comment: Why have the repeat when the count is 1? Also it might be something to do with the anchor point seeing as a circle rotating about it's centre doesn't appear to rotate at all?

Comment: @TonyMkenu that didn't do anything

Comment: @AndyHeard The repeat will change with later code. Circle doesn't appear to rotate at all

any suggestions?

Comment: is your `round` `SKShapeNode` a property of the class?

Comment: @rakeshbs sorry I'm not sure. Still new to this :/